# Mock Class for class parameter in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class Client. 
It has the methods as follows,

```
public class Client
{
   public Client(string portNum);
   public void Init();
   public void SendMsg(byte[] msg);
   public byte[] Receive();
}
```

I'm using the class for communication. Client is class in a 3rd party library, So I can't edit the class Client.

I need to write a Mock class for Client to do unit test for my class.
I'm using Visual studio unit test. .Net 4.5.
For the Mock, I'm using Moq.dll.
I try as follows,

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestSend()
        {
            var mockClient = new Mock<Client>();
            mockClient.Setup(x => x.SendMsg(It.IsAny<byte[]>())).Callback<byte[]>((m) => Send(m));
            Assert.IsTrue(isInit);
        }

    private void Send(byte[] msg)
    {

    }
```

It is throwing en exception as follows,

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   Moq.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in
>   VB) member: x => x.SendMsg(It.IsAny())

Can anybody tel the mistake, I have done. And how to correct it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm using a dll. Client is a class in the dll.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comment says it all - you cannot mock in this way.

What you can do:

#### 1. setup a (lean) interface with all you need:

```
public interface IClient
{
   public void Init();
   public void SendMsg(byte[] msg);
   public byte[] Receive();
}
```

#### 2. make a facade around client to implement it:

```
public class MyClient : IClient
{
   private Client _client;

   /* implement everything in the obvious way by using the private field */
}
```

#### 3. use the interface instead of `Client` in **your** code

sorry did not see anything on this

just insert `IClient` instead of `Client` and inject it in your constructors.

#### 4. Mock the interface

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSend()
{
   var mockClient = new Mock<IClient>();
   mockClient.Setup(x => x.SendMsg(It.IsAny<byte[]>())).Callback<byte[]>((m) => Send(m));

   // ....
   Assert.IsTrue(isInit);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight tweak to Carsten's answer, which is already very thorough.

When you create your own class, extend the `Client` class and implement the interface, like this: *(assuming the "Client" class is not sealed, in which case this wouldn't work)*

```
public class DerivedClient : Client, IClient
{
    public DerivedClient(string portNum)
        : base(portNum) {}
}
```

This way, you don't have to copy all the methods from the base `Client` class (there's only 3 in this case, but it could be more in another scenario), since it's really just a pass-through to everything in the base `Client` class.

Ideally, if you're using a DI service such as Unity, you'll configure it to instantiate `DerivedClient` when an instance of `IClient` is requested.